# CSS: Horizontal and Vertical spacing around tables

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table

I am looking for a way to display 5 HTML tables in the below mentioned format on IE8:

```
<Table1>    <Table2>

<Table3>    <Table4>

<Table5>
```

That is, having both horizontal and vertical space between tables.
Would highly appreciate if anyone provides recommendations around the same,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set margin and float: http://jsfiddle.net/GEKVX/7/

Answer (score 1):

CSS can help you in this matter.

Just read about

1) Float
2) Align
3) Padding
4) Flow

Answer (score 0):

Put those tables inside a table (i.e. use a parent table).

Comment: Table itself is not tabular data, therefore should not be placed inside a table. Also tables should not be used to position elements.